# Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Is any linearly order space Hausdorff space? why?

I think strongly the answer is yes. I took N natural number and I see for every 2 points x,y in it there exist 2  NBHDs of x,y call them U,V s.t. U(intersect)V= the empty set.

Is that true for all linearly order set.

Comment: Its in Munkres ,you can check that .. the argument is right

Comment: Your argument is correct, for any two points $a$ and $b$ (assume that $a > b$) we have $(a, \infty) \cap (-\infty, b) = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

It works in general but the argument is more delicate than with natural numbers. It is almost a mix of the situation that happens with real numbers and the one that happens with natural numbers.

Let $X$ be a totally ordered set, made into a topological space with the order topology; so a basis for the topology are the open intervals $(a,b)$ with $a< b$. Given $x,y \in X$, we want to find neighborhoods of $U_x,U_y$ such that $U_x \cap U_y = \emptyset$.

Assume $x < y$. We distinguish two cases: $(x,y) = \emptyset$ and $(x,y) \neq \emptyset$.

If $(x,y) = \emptyset$, define $U_x = (- \infty, y)$ and $U_y = (x,+\infty)$. They are open, $x \in U_x$ and $y \in U_y$ and $U_x \cap U_y = (x,y) = \emptyset$, so they are disjoint open neighborhoods separating $x$ and $y$.

If $(x,y) \neq \emptyset$ let $z \in (x,y)$ and define $U_x = (-\infty, z)$, $U_y = (z, +\infty)$. Again they are open neighborhoods separating $x$ and $y$.